# Efficient faithfully-rounded implementation of error function erff()

Tags: c, floating-point

The error function is closely related to the standard normal distribution and occurs frequently in the natural sciences as well as other fields. It is used in finance when pricing options, for example. While support for it was added first to ISO C99 and subsequently to C++ in the form of the functions `erf()`, `erff()`, it was until recently absent from at least one popular C/C+ toolchain. Many projects still use their own implementations of the error function, often based on approximations from older literature, such as [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_299.htm), 
which in turn go back to

*Cecil Hastings Jr, "Approximations for Digital Computers". Princeton University Press, 1955*

In modern computing, faithfully-rounded implementations of transcendental functions are often seen as a minimal standard of accuracy for math libraries; such a standard still allows for high-performance implementations. A function is called faithfully rounded when it returns results with a maximum error of less than 1 [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) compared with the mathematical value across the entire input domain. Older published algorithms do not provide faithfully-rounded results when implemented with exclusive use of IEEE-754 single precision operations.

Modern computer hardware provides an floating-point operation called fused multiply-add (or FMA for short) that computes a floating-point multiplication followed by a dependent floating-point addition such that the full unrounded product is used in the addition, and only a single rounding occurs at the end of the operation. This fused operation, introduced by IBM in 1990, provides higher accuracy and higher performance in many computations. It is available on the two most prevalent CPU architectures today (ARM and x86) as well as on GPUs. It has been exposed in C and C++ via the `fmaf()` and `fmaf()` functions.

Assuming that FMA is natively supported by hardware, how would one construct a  single-precision error function `erff()` which is both faithfully rounded and efficient? Preferrably, the code should be vectorizable, possibly after minor code modification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the [graph of the error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), one observes that the function is symmetric about the origin; approximations can therefore trivially be restricted to the positive half-plane. Furthermore, the graph could be split into two segments, with the boundary between these somewhere near x = 1. In the segment closer to the origin, the error function is fairly linear and vertically dominated, while in the segment further away from the origin it is horizontally dominated and asymptotically approaches unity in exponentially decaying fashion.

A reasonable conclusion is that a simple polynomial approximation x * p (x) is suitable for the segment close to zero, while the other segment would be well approximated by 1 - exp (x * q (x)), where q (x) is a second polynomial approximation. Based on the Taylor series expansion of the error
function, the approximation for the segment near the origin should actually be of the form x * p (x<sup>2</sup>).

The first task then is to find the switch-over point between the two segments. I used an experimental approach for this, starting with the switch-over point at 0.875 and incrementally marching it towards 1.0. For each value of the switch-over point, I generated an initial minimax approximation to the error function between zero and the switch-over point with the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm). These were then further improved, in terms of accuracy, using search
heuristics for the coefficient values based on evaluation of the polynomial via Horner scheme with use of FMA operations. Incrementing the switch-over point was repeated until the maximum error of the resulting approximation exceeded 1 ulp. By this process I determined the optimal boundary between the two approximation segments as 475/512 = 0.927734375. This results in an approximation x * p (x<sup>2</sup>) that achieves a maximum error of barely less than 1 ulp.

The Remez algorithm was also used to provide an initial minimax computation for the polynomial q (x). It became clear early on that there is a fair amount of interaction between q (x) and the approximation used internally
to exp() in the way their errors reinforce or compensate each other. This means the best choice for the coefficients of q (x) will be tightly tied to the implementation of `exp()` and must be taken into account as part of the heuristic refinement of the initial set of coefficients. I therefore decided to use my own implementation of `expf()` so as to isolate myself from
any particular library implementation. As a minimum requirement, `expf()` itself needs to be faithfully rounded, and probably must conform to a slightly tighter error bound for this approach to work, although I did not try to determine exactly how tight. In this case my own implementation of `expf()` provides an error bound of 0.86565 ulps, which turned out to be sufficient.

Because the computation above the switch-over point uses `1 - exp (...)`, it seems tempting to use `expm1()` instead of `exp()`, but for most platforms `exp()` is one of the most highly optimized functions in the math library, so using `expm1()` may not provide significant (or even any) benefits.

Since the segment requiring use of exp () is the slow path, I chose to use
[Estrin's scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrin%27s_scheme) for the low-order terms of the polynomial q (x) in order to increase instruction-level parallelism and thus performance. The impact on accuracy of doing so is negligible. For accuracy reasons, the Horner scheme must be utilized for the high-order terms of the polynomial. Looking at the least-significant coefficients of both polynomials, one observes that both are  1.128..., and we can therefore improve accuracy slightly by splitting the coefficient into (1 + 0.128...), which facilitates the use of FMA to perform the final multiplication with x.

In the end I was able to achieve an implementation of `erff()` where each of the two code paths achieves a maximum error of just under 1 ulp, as established by exhaustive test against a higher-precision reference. The function is therefore faithfully rounded. Use of FMA is a crucial component of this success. Depending on toolchain, the C99 code shown below may be vectorizable as-is, or one could modify it manually such that both code paths are computed concurrently with a selection of the desired result at the end. High-performance math libraries include a vectorizable version of `expf()` which should be used instead of my custom function `my_expf()`. Not all vectorized implementations of `expf()` offer sufficient accuracy though, and for others tuning of the coefficients in polynomial q (x) will be necessary.

If a custom version of `expf()` is used, like I did here, one would want to replace calls to `ldexpf()` with faster machine-specific code for performance reasons. An example of such an optimization, suitable for IEEE-754 `binary32` mapped to `float` is shown in `my_expf()` below.

```c
float my_expf (float);
float my_expm1f (float);

/* compute error function with maximum error 0.99527 ulp */
float my_erff (float a)
{
    float r, s, t, u;
 
    t = fabsf (a);
    s = a * a;
    if (t > 0.927734375f) { // 475/512
        // maximum error 0.99527 ulp
        r = fmaf (-1.72853470e-5f, t, 3.83197126e-4f); // -0x1.220000p-16,0x1.91cfb2p-12 
        u = fmaf (-3.88396438e-3f, t, 2.42546219e-2f); // -0x1.fd1438p-9, 0x1.8d6342p-6
        r = fmaf (r, s, u);
        r = fmaf (r, t, -1.06777877e-1f); // -0x1.b55cb8p-4
        r = fmaf (r, t, -6.34846687e-1f); // -0x1.450aa0p-1
        r = fmaf (r, t, -1.28717512e-1f); // -0x1.079d0cp-3
        r = fmaf (r, t, -t);
#if USE_EXPM1
        r = my_expm1f (r);
#else // USE_EXPM1
        r = 1.0f - my_expf (r);
#endif // USE_EXPM1
        r = copysignf (r, a);
    } else { 
        // maximum error 0.98929 ulp
        r =             -5.96761703e-4f;  // -0x1.38e000p-11
        r = fmaf (r, s,  4.99119423e-3f); //  0x1.471a58p-8
        r = fmaf (r, s, -2.67681349e-2f); // -0x1.b691b2p-6
        r = fmaf (r, s,  1.12819925e-1f); //  0x1.ce1c44p-4
        r = fmaf (r, s, -3.76125336e-1f); // -0x1.812700p-2
        r = fmaf (r, s,  1.28379166e-1f); //  0x1.06eba8p-3
        r = fmaf (r, a, a);
    } 
    return r;
}

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

/* compute exp(a) with maximum error 0.86565 ulp */
float my_expf (float a)
{
    float f, r, j;
    int i;

    // exp(a) = 2**i * exp(f); i = rintf (a / log(2))
    j = fmaf (1.442695f, a, 12582912.f) - 12582912.f; // 0x1.715476p0, 0x1.8p23
    f = fmaf (j, -6.93145752e-1f, a); // -0x1.62e400p-1  // log_2_hi 
    f = fmaf (j, -1.42860677e-6f, f); // -0x1.7f7d1cp-20 // log_2_lo 
    i = (int)j;
    // approximate r = exp(f) on interval [-log(2)/2, +log(2)/2]
    r =             1.37805939e-3f;  // 0x1.694000p-10
    r = fmaf (r, f, 8.37312452e-3f); // 0x1.125edcp-7
    r = fmaf (r, f, 4.16695364e-2f); // 0x1.555b5ap-5
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.66664720e-1f); // 0x1.555450p-3
    r = fmaf (r, f, 4.99999851e-1f); // 0x1.fffff6p-2
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.00000000e+0f); // 0x1.000000p+0
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.00000000e+0f); // 0x1.000000p+0
#if PORTABLE
    // exp(a) = 2**i * r
    r = ldexpf (r, i);
#else // PORTABLE
    float s, t;
    uint32_t ia;
    // exp(a) = 2**i * r
    ia = (i > 0) ?  0 : 0x83000000u;
    s = uint32_as_float (0x7f000000u + ia);
    t = uint32_as_float (((uint32_t)i << 23) - ia);
    r = r * s;
    r = r * t;
#endif // PORTABLE
    // handle special cases: severe overflow / underflow
    if (fabsf (a) >= 104.0f) r = (a > 0) ? INFINITY : 0.0f;
    return r;
}

/* compute exp(a)-1 with maximum error 0.997458 ulp */
float my_expm1f (float a)
{
    float f, j, r, s, t, u, v, x, y;
    int i;

    // exp(a) = 2**i * exp(f); i = rintf (a / log(2))
    j = fmaf (1.442695f, a, 12582912.f); // 0x1.715476p0, 0x1.8p23
#if PORTABLE
    j = j - 12582912.0f; // 0x1.8p23
    i = (int)j;
#else // PORTABLE    
    i = float_as_uint32 (j); // trailing bits contain integer
    j = j - 12582912.f; // 0x1.8p23
#endif // PORTABLE
    f = fmaf (j, -6.93145752e-1f, a); // -0x1.62e400p-1  // log_2_hi 
    f = fmaf (j, -1.42860677e-6f, f); // -0x1.7f7d1cp-20 // log_2_lo
    // approximate r = exp(f)-1 on interval [-log(2)/2, +log(2)/2]
    s = f * f;
    if (a == 0.0f) s = a; // ensure -0 is passed through
    r =             1.97947025e-4f;  // 0x1.9f2000p-13
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.39317091e-3f); // 0x1.6d361ep-10
    r = fmaf (r, f, 8.33333656e-3f); // 0x1.111118p-7
    r = fmaf (r, f, 4.16667797e-2f); // 0x1.555592p-5
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.66666716e-1f); // 0x1.55555cp-3
    r = fmaf (r, f, 4.99999970e-1f); // 0x1.fffffep-2
    // if i == 0, expm1(a) = z
    // if i == 1, expm1(a) = 2*(r*(f*f)+f+0.5)
    // if (i < 0) || (i > 1) expm1(a) = 2*((r*(f*f)+f)*t-0.5+t)
    u = (j == 1) ? (f + 0.5f) : f;
    v = fmaf (r, s, u);
    s = 0.5f;
#if PORTABLE
    t = ldexpf (s, i);
#else // PORTABLE
    t = uint32_as_float (((uint32_t)i << 23) + float_as_uint32 (s));
#endif // PORTABLE
    y = t - s;
    x = (t - y) - s; // double-float canonicalization of difference
    r = fmaf (v, t, x) + y;
    r = r + r;
    if (j == 0) r = v;
    if (j == 1) r = v + v;
    if (fabsf (a - 1.0f) > 88.0f) r = (a < 0.0f) ? (-1.0f) : INFINITY;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: What's the error like in the top branch just before the `r = 1.0f - r`? That is, if someone adapted the above function to give the complementary error function `erfc` rather than `erf`, is the result still faithfully rounded?

Comment: That approximation, referred to as polynomial q() above, is unsuitable for the computation of `erfcf()`. Since `erff (4.0f) == 1.0f`, here we only need an approximation that is accurate on [0.921875, 4], and it doesn't even have to be terribly accurate, in terms of ulp error, near the right end-point. For `erfc()` there is a long "tail" that must be computed accurately, posing a much harder problem. I don't have any ideas at this time how to compute that faithfully-rounded yet fast.

Comment: 1)  When I use this code, I'll have to provide a bounty 2) Confident, adjusting the set-up used for calculating optimal result for `float`, that the `double` (maybe `long double`) best results could also be posted.

Comment: Alas, I do not have an equivalent solution for `double` or higher precisions, nor do I have a realistic way yet of finding one. The reason is that the iterative processes and search heuristics I used are impractically slow when used with higher precision. With `float` computation each coefficient set can be checked exhaustively on the relevant interval in seconds.

Comment: Going up in degree by one can get you a fast-path polynomial that's faithfully-rounded on [0,1].  Its coefficients are 0x1.900c1cp-14, -0x1.c16a0ep-11, 0x1.58a476p-8, -0x1.b8a2ep-6, 0x1.ce3782p-4, -0x1.81276ep-2, 0x1.06eba6p-3.  Not certain how much that helps...

Comment: @tmyklebu Thanks for the coefficient data. I did initially consider [0,1] for the fast-path interval. The trade-off (slightly wider fast-path interval versus additional term in the fast-path polynomial) seems to be entirely application dependent, and the effect seems to be minor. I think you should have mentioned your paper where you describe your heuristic for generating the coefficients for minimax polynomial approximations evaluated with FMAs: http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03211

Comment: (Deleted a comment that came from my failure to recognise the evaluation of a cubic via Estrin's scheme.)

Comment: Dear @njuffa -- it's been a while since your original post, but I had a question about it that I hope you could answer. In particular, I was wondering if you could provide further detail on the heuristics search that you used to find a nearby polynomial that accounts for the fact that single precision FMA is used to evaluate the polynomial? Thanks!

Comment: @WenzelJakob The heuristic I use personally is probably best described as a form of simulated annealing. It is a bit on the brute-force side, often using numerous cycles of heating and cooling. The results are frequently, but not always, competitive with those achieved by other people's heuristics.

Comment: @njuffa: I suspected something like that. Could you provide detail on your temperature schedule and exchange operations. Do you change one coefficient at a time, or all of them, and by multiple ULPs or just a single one (something like nextafter)? I'm trying to replicate your results to obtain similarly high quality fits for a bunch of functions. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: @WenzelJakob I usually allow all the coefficients to change simultaneously, but have  on occasion manually fixed some of them. Amount of change (multiples of ulp) varies with the temperature. This is a bit of my secret sauce, so I don't want to reveal all the details at this time. Biggest issue still: getting stuck on local minima. I usually optimize for two goals simultaneously: minimize max. ulp error as the primary goal, minimize the sum of ulp errors (basically a measure of overall accuracy) as secondary goal. I have considered genetic algorithms in the past but never implemented one.

Comment: @njuffa: thank you, this was extremely helpful. I've implemented a basic annealer, which appears to find faithfully rounded polynomials for erf() [I need to do more careful brute force checks through the whole interval though to be sure]. It's interesting that annealing for Estrin's scheme all the way appears to be very difficult, as you had already pointed out. One last question: how do you validate the mean/max ULP error? I generate something like 100K uniformly distributed ground truth evaluations ahead of time and then test wrt. those, but I'm unsure whether that is stringent enough..

Comment: @WenzelJakob For single-argument, single-precision math functions I use exhaustive tests. Typically takes half an hour or less on my workstation (3.6 GHz Skylake). For two-argument or double-precision math functions I use (targeted) random tests, typically around 1B to 4B test cases. That can take half a day or so, as I need to use an arbitrary-precision library as the reference.

Comment: @WenzelJakob By using `expm1` in the upper interval, one can usually relax a bit on the accuracy of the polynomial approximation. I used `exp` here because that is typically the more highly optimized function in terms of performance. Instead of using Estrin's scheme for the first steps, a second-order Horner scheme should also work well.

Comment: @njuffaThanks for the detailed explanation. Can you please tell me which tool did you use to arrive at the coefficients of the polynomial? I am familiar with the sollya tool. Also can you please tell me how did you arrive at both the polynomial?

Comment: @JosephArnold I use my own  home-grown software. A starting point is provided by the Remez algorithm, and this is followed by a heuristic search (similar to simulated annealing). The `fpminimax` command of Sollya provides very good coefficients, but I would like to think that my own approach can find slightly better coefficients *for a specific context* (order of operations).