# Why hexadecimal floating constants in C++17?

Tags: c++, floating-point, constants, c++17

C++17 to add hexadecimal floating constant ([floating point literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)). Why? How about a couple of examples showing the benefits.

Comment: (1) For long-overdue compatibility with C (starting with ISO C99) (2) To *unambiguously* define floating-point constants (for IEEE-754 binary floating-point formats in particular), without the bugs often affecting conversions from decimal floating-point (see [Rick Regan's blog](http://www.exploringbinary.com/) for examples of such bugs in modern, commonly used, software)

Comment: An example for the need to unambiguously specify literal floating-point constants would be creation of code for math library functions, e.g. [`atanf`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692859/best-machine-optimized-polynomial-minimax-approximation-to-arctangent-on-1-1), [`erff`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148198/efficient-faithfully-rounded-implementation-of-error-function-erff), [`expf`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381117/which-exponentiation-algorithms-do-cpu-programming-languages-use)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Floating point numbers are stored in x86/x64 processors in base 2, not base 10: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format . Because of that many decimal floating point numbers cannot be represented exactly, e.g decimal 0.1 could be represented as something like 0.1000000000000003 or 0.0999999999999997 - whatever has base 2 representation close enough to decimal 0.1 . Because of that inexactness, e.g. printing in decimal and then parsing of a floating-point number may result in a slightly different number than the one stored in memory binarily before printing.

For some application emergence of such errors is unacceptable: they want to parse into exactly the same binary floating-point number as the one which was before printing (e.g. one application exports floating-point data and another imports). For that, one could export and import doubles in hexadecimal format. Because 16 is a power of 2, binary floating-point numbers can be represented exactly in hexadecimal format.

`printf` and `scanf` have been extended with `%a` format specifier which allows to print and parse hexadecimal floating point numbers. Though [MSVC++ does not support `%a` format specifier for `scanf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ttkkkhh.aspx) yet:

> The a and A specifiers (see printf Type Field Characters) are not available with scanf.

To print a `double` in full precision with hexadecimal format one should specify printing of 13 hexadecimal digits after point, which correspond to 13*4=52 bits:

```
double x = 0.1;
printf("%.13a", x);
```

See more details on [hexadecimal floating point with code and examples](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/) (note that at least for MSVC++ 2013 simple specification of `%a` in `printf` prints 6 hexadecimal digits after point, not 13 - this is stated in the end of the article).

Specifically for constants, as asked in the question, hexadecimal constants may be convenient for testing the application on exact hard-coded floating-point inputs. E.g. your bug may be reproducible for 0.1000000000000003, but not for 0.0999999999999997, so you need hexadecimal hardcoded value to specify the representation of interest for decimal 0.1 .

Comment: The examples shown in the article are for gcc. In the last paragraph of the article I say to use “%.13a” instead of “%a" for VC++.

Comment: @RickRegan , sorry, didn't notice that end of the article initially. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Note that `1` all floating point numbers in base `a` is representible in base `b` if and only if `b` is divisible by all prime factors of `a`, `2` so all numbers in base 2 can be represented exactly in base 10 too, and `3` 17 decimal digits are enough for `double` to round-trip.

Answer (score 2):

The main 2 reasons to use hex floats over decimals are accuracy and speed.

The algorithms for accurately converting between decimal constants and the underlying binary format of floating point numbers are [surprisingly complicated](http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-strtod-works-and-sometimes-doesnt/), and even nowadays [conversion errors still occasionally arise](http://www.exploringbinary.com/tag/bug/).

Converting between hexadecimal and binary is a much simpler endeavour, and guaranteed to be exact. An example use case is when it is critical that you use a specific floating point number, and not one either side (e.g. for implementations of special functions such as `exp`). This simplicity also makes the conversion much faster (it doesn't require any intermediate "bignum" arithmetic): in some cases I've seen 3x speed up for read/write operations for hex float vs decimals.

Comment: I don't understand how this could make code faster. E.g. `0xA.0f` should be *exactly* the same as `10.0f` at the bit level, so how could the source-code representation possibly make the implementation any faster? Why any runtime conversion at all?

Comment: I meant if you were using `printf` or `fscanf`

Comment: wait what if one platform uses base2 floats and other uses decimal floats? ieee 754 supposes various formats

Comment: There aren't that many platforms that support decimal floats in hardware, and those that do still tend to keep binary floats as the default, keeping decimal as a secondary type.

Comment: Re "guaranteed to be exact": Only if there are enough bits to represent, of course. | The question is about _constant_, not _reading/writing_.